# Magento2 text not getting translated when added in ar_SA.csv

Tags: magento2, translate

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Reorder/Reorder.php

Could not add the product with SKU "%1" to the shopping cart: %2
```

The above mentioned text si not getting translated when adding data in CSV.

Can some one please guide?

In CSV I added as below

```
Could not add the product with SKU "%1" to the shopping cart: %2,Could not add the product with SKU78 "%1" to the shopping cart: %2,,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use repeated quotes in the translation file:

```
Could not add the product with SKU ""%1"" to the shopping cart: %2
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Put this at the end of file**

```
"Could not add the product with SKU %1 to the shopping cart: %2","Could not add the product with SKU78 %1 to the shopping cart: %2"
```